# Combine two formulas for multiple inputs

Tags: google-sheets, regexplace

I'm attempting to figure out how to combine these two formulas when there are multiple inputs.

Example inputs:

https://tracking.com/123456789
https://tracking.com/123456789?ABCD

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(XXX,"http://tracking.com/",""),"?ABCD","")

=REGEXREPLACE(XXX,"https://tracking.com/",)

Output should only show: 123456789

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Hi and welcome! May be `=REGEXEXTRACT(<source cell>,"\d+")`? See help on [**REGEXTRACT()**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since your first formula works with both of the examples you provided, I believe you want to get the same results with your second formula as well. In this case, just change it as follows:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(<source cell>,"https://tracking.com/",),"\?ABCD",)
```

- note that the `question mark` had to be escaped with a `backslash` because by itself it would have meant something else [?, if unescaped, matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)]